# Power supply ringing when servo activates

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm running a servo from a 12V -> 5V buck regulator. The servo has a stall current of about 500mA and a nominal operating current of about 200mA. Here's a scope reading from when the servo starts moving:

(output side)

[image]

(input side)

[image]

The output voltage drops from 5.3V to 3.8V and then climbs back up, while the input voltage drops from 11.8 to about 10.2. The time scale is 20ms / div. I have a 250uA electrolytic cap near the servo power pin. Is this "ladder" normal? Or is something not right with my regulator?

The reg is an [LM2734](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2734.pdf), which can do 1A, with a 4.7uH inductor with a 1.2A saturation point. The input is 8 AA Alkaline batteries.

Here's the servo circuit:

[image]

And here's the regulator:

[image]

Comment: It seems servo starts drawing more current in initial phase, resulting in voltage drop.

Comment: Take a look at the input voltage to the switcher - what does it do when the servo operates?

Comment: I'd try experimenting with different caps first. Add smaller cap values in addition to the big 250µF one, they react faster on the steep voltage drops. Depending on how the waveform changes with different caps you might get an idea what could help.

Comment: The output cap appears large to me, does behaviour improve if you change it to approximately 10 ~ 22µF? The datasheet proposes the use of very low ESR (ceramic SMD) output cap. Also check the chapter named "OUTPUT
CAPACITOR".

Comment: I might try replacing the motor with a ~10 ohm resistor and see how it responds.  (Perhaps it's something to do with the motor inductance.)

Comment: @jippie The cap on the servo isn't the output cap, it's an additional one. The switcher has a 22uF mlcc output cap.

Comment: @Andyaka added that too

Comment: Aren't the values above for a 3.3volt regulator not 5V?

Comment: They are, there was a mistake in my schematic but the actual resistor values are correct (56k instead of 31.6)

Comment: Is your input supply actually a battery? Please describe it in your question - type of supply, rating (if a source) / capacity and tecnhology (if a battery) - the fact that the load change is causing the input to sag by 1.5V is going to be difficult to work around when there doesn't appear to be an input feed-forward within the IC.

Comment: Added, but it's just a 8xAA batteries.

Comment: -1 for leading everyone astray. A halfhearted attempt at a circuit helps nobody and just wastes time.

Comment: If by everyone you mean the one person that didn't read the reply to his direct question, followed by an updated schematic, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the time period of the peaks on the recovery of the bulk capacitance. By eye it looks like 5ms peek-to-peek, or ~200hz from your time base. The regulator datasheet reports the switching frequency of the buck-boost is internally set to 550kHz (LM2734Y) or 1.6MHz (LM2734X). This suggests the recovery waveform is dominated by something other than the boost injections of charge.

I might be tempted to try a diode between the supply side and the motor/bulk capacitance, on the assumption that there's some oscillation between the bulk capacitance and the charging L-C network that interferes with the feedback sense. You'd have to raise the output voltage of the buck-boost to compensate for the voltage drop across the charging diode

Is the converter a pre-assembled board or did you choose the various capacitor types yourself - what are they?

Comment: I chose the caps myself based on their recommendations. Except the 250uF electrolytic cap by the servo, the rest are MLCC SMD caps. 22uF for the output, 10uF for the input. And - fwiw, this is the 1.6MHz model.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has been made null and void by the OP updating the question to show the correct value of feedback resistor for 5V regulation - thanks!

I have a suspicion that there are two problems here. First problem - your circuit diagram contains values of feedback resistors that are for a 3.3 volt regulation point on the output. The second problem is that you may not be supplying enough minimum load for the 3.3 volt to become regulated - minimum duty cycle is 1 or 2 % and this will likely mean that under light load conditions the output voltage rises above 3.3 volts - you think you have designed a 5 volt regulator but, because the minimum loading needed to keep the output stable at 3.3 volt isn't applied, it drifts up to ~5V. You yourself say the output voltage is 5.3V and this is too much of a coincidence to believe it is a 5V regulator in regulation.

So, when you apply the load of 200mA, the minimum loading requirements of the chip are met and it starts to go into regulation. When the load is released, it heads upwards of the regulation point because minimum load requirements are not met.

Comment: As I said in my comment to you - there was a mistake in my schematic, but the actual resistor value in the divider is 56.2K, which sets it for ~5.2V operation.

Comment: And re: the second point, if that's the case, does it do any harm, and is this ~20ms ramp the only effect? The servo is operating normally, I just want to make sure that this waveform isn't going to cause me issues elsewhere.

Comment: We'd need the rest of your system schematic to help you with that.  SMPS cause problems all the time since they are very noisy.  Your issue is, I would say, very critical.  Other problems wouldn't be surprising if you don't fix this.  Driving a .5A load with an SMPS shouldn't be putting this much strain on the power supply.

Answer (score -2):

have a look at the comp signal for your switched power suppy.
(just post a question my self on what the best way is to get the right value for this to make sure of stable operation over the full load range)

sorry did not check your voltage regulators datasheet. as it don't have a compensation input.

is your cap low ESR as a low ESR cap will do better here. you can also add some high uF ceramic caps also can help as they are very fast as well. as if the current durring start up is high

Comment: This is more a comment that an answer.